# how to make an insert function with in a database class to insert a new record with multiple coloumns and multiple values (using PDO )?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

the problem is my function *insert* inserts my record in two rows.

this is my code to connect to database in a file named :

**connect.php**

```
<?php
try{
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NPD" , "root" , "");

echo "connected";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

this is my database class in a file

**database.php**

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';
class DB {
public function insertInto($tableName , $info){
        global $db;
        foreach ($info as $coloumnName => $coloumnValue) {          
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $tableName ($coloumnName) VALUES ('$coloumnValue') ");
            $stmt->execute();   
        }
    }
}
$da = new DB;
$da->insertInto('tableOne',array('name' => 'lolo' , 'deg' => '100'));
```

the result in the database is :
[tableOne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYLwv.jpg)

how can to make the *insert* function inserts my record in one row.

*note* : i want to insert any number of columns and values.

Comment: Well, first of all I would combine the connect method into the DB class, are you ever going to make a DB class without a connection?  Secondly, split the sql, put the `Insert into ...` up to and including the word `VALUES`, then in the loop make an array for `values` and add each set as a element then implode it.  Oh and get rid of that global...

Comment: `Insert into $tablename ( $column1, $column2, $column3) values ('$val1, $val2, $val3)` should be the target of your loop, but what you do is executing with only one key=>value per line and the executinog it multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to do something like this:

```
$arr = array('name' => 'lolo' , 'deg' => '100');
$columns=array_keys($arr);
$values=array_values($arr);

           $str="INSERT INTO $tableName (".implode(',',$columns).") VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $values) . "' )";
           echo $str;//your sql
         //  $stmt = $db->prepare($str);
         //  $stmt->execute();//uncomment to execute
```

Comment: That is a very nice version. It is not as easy to understand, but it has only one query going to the DB, instead of having a lethal query inside a loop. God Job Bro!

Answer (score 1):

Like this but there are some concerns ( also I haven't tested this )

```
class DB {

    protected $_conn;

    public function __construct( $user, $pass, $database='NPD', $host='localhost' ){
        try{
            $this->_conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$database}" , $user , $pass);
            echo "connected";
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function insertInto($tableName , $info){
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO $tableName (';
            $sql .= '`'implode('`,`', array_keys($info[0])).'`';
            $sql .= ')VALUES';


            foreach ($info as $index => $row) {   
                $sql .= '(';
                foreach( $row as $column => $value){
                    $sql .= ':'.$column.$index.',';
                    $params[':'.$column.$index] = $value;
                }
                $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
                $sql .= '),';
            }
            $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');

            $stmt = $this->_conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute($params);   
        }
    }
}
$da = new DB('root', '');
$da->insertInto('tableOne',array( array('name' => 'lolo' , 'deg' => '100') ) );
```

First of all you loose any sql injection protection on the column names.  If you can manage the placeholders on the values, then that is ok, but without using them there you loose protection on that as well. This can be solved by using the db schema itself, via `Show columns` but that gets a wee bit complex.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html

Second, your input array structure is all wrong, it needs to be `array(0=>array(...), 1=>array(...))` instead of just `array(...)`

Third I would make this class a "Singleton" but that's just me

http://coderoncode.com/design-patterns/programming/php/development/2014/01/27/design-patterns-php-singletons.html

Forth, if you just want to do a single row at a time you can change this method

```
 public function insertInto($tableName , $info){
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO $tableName (';
        $sql .= '`'implode('`,`', array_keys($info)).'`';
        $sql .= ')VALUES(';

        $params = array();
        foreach( $info as $column => $value){
            $sql .= ':'.$column.$index.',';
            $params[':'.$column.$index] = $value;
        }
        $sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
        $sql .= ')';

        $stmt = $this->_conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);   
}
```

And use the current input array structure you have.

Answer (score 0):

This Is how i coded my own insert function

```
        public function insertRecord($table,$records){
          //A variable to store all the placeholders for my PDO INSERT values.
            $placeholder = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($records); $i++){
                $placeholder[$i] = '?';
            }
     //A FOR-LOOP to loop through the records in the $record array
            $placeholder = implode(',', $placeholder);
 //Imploding ',' in between the placeholders

            $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES ("{$placeholder}")";
            $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute($records);
          }
```

It Might not be the best..worked for me though.

Answer (score 0):

As some other answers/comments have stated, there are quite a few critiques one could make about this overall process. However, in the interests of simply answering the question, you may want to just build the statement by looping through the columns, then looping through the values, then executing the finished statement (code below is just an example and hasn't been tested):

```
require 'connect.php';
class DB {
public function insertInto($tableName , $info){
        global $db;        
        $query = "INSERT INTO $tableName (";
        $columns = array_keys($info);

        // build the columns in the statement
        $length = count($columns);
        foreach($columns as $index => $column) {
            $query .= "$column";
            if ($index+1 < $length) {
                $query .= ','
            }            
        }

        $query .= ") VALUES ("

        // build the values in the statement
        $i = 1;
        $length = count($info);
        foreach($info as $value) {
            $query .= "'$value'"
            if ($i < $length) {
                $query .= ","
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $query .= ")"

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
$da = new DB;
$da->insertInto('tableOne',array('name' => 'lolo' , 'deg' => '100'));
```